# Confused by this Javascript shorthand

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I don't understand how this shorthand works:

```
nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.y += i & 1 ? k : -k;
    o.x += i & 2 ? k : -k;
});
```

I have never seen an increment operator in shorthand like this.

Thanks

Comment: Which part of this is troublesome?  Is it the `a ? b : c` (ternary operator)?  Or is it the `&` (bitwise and)?

Comment: @mwcz: That's the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Guffa's answer explains it :)

Comment: @mwcz: I know what it does do, it's only called differently than what you wrote.

Comment: It's checking if the number `i` is odd or even. And adding or subtracting if either is true.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel It's also commonly called the "[ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A)".  "Conditional operator" is a more accurate name, but don't be surprised if you see it called the ternary operator (because it's the only ternary operator in most languages, afaik).

Answer (score 2):

The expression `i & 1 ? k : -k` evaluates to either `k` or `-k` depending on whether `i & 1` evaluates to `true` or not.

The `&` operator does a bitwise 'and' between the operators, so the first condition checks if the least significant bit is set, and the second condition checks if the second least significant bit is set.

The code does the same as:

```
nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
  if (i & 1) {
    o.y += k;
  } else {
    o.y -= k;
  }
  if (i & 2) {
    o.x += k;
  } else {
    o.x -= k;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`1` is `0000...0001`

`2` is `0000...0010`

`i` probably stores a set of flags set as bits on an int.

`i & 1` simply tests the last bit is set and `i & 2` tests the one before is set. See [the MDN on bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

You can store about 52 flags in a javascript number using this system :

```
i = 0; // no flag
i |= 4; // sets a flag
i |= 1<<2; // sets the same flag but is more readable
var bool = i & 4; // truish if the flag is set
```

So your code does this :

```
if i has flag 1 then o.y += k else o.y += -k
if i has flag 2 then o.x += k else o.x += -k
```

Comment: Could this be a test for even/odd?  (I'm not saying it's a good test) if i is odd then increase o.y by k else decrease o.y by k

Comment: No, the second test has nothing to see with oddity, it really looks like a flag storage (which was very common in C).